# Need to downgrade MySQL authentication scheme to use pgloader for PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to import a MySQL database into PostgreSQL using the pgloader utility.

Because pgloader doesn't support caching_sha2_password authentication plugin, which is default for MySQL 8, I need to use the mysql_native_password plugin.

I'm trying [this fix](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/782#issuecomment-502323324) on MySQL 8.0.32 Homebrew.

However, the query `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'secret';` returns `Query OK, 0 rows affected`, is that to be expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query OK, 0 rows affected` Is Expected. As it has not affected any records in tables. You can cross-verify this by logging in with username and your password.

SQL Commands that do not explicitly name tables have `0 row(s) affected`

Such commands that echo `0 row(s) affected` include

```
CREATE USER / ALTER USER
GRANT/REVOKE
CHANGE MASTER TO (to Setup MySQL Replication)
```